# Contour colors don't correspond to color bar when a surf plot is added

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colorbar

Below is some code that recreates my problem as simplified as I can make it.  It does a subplot with two plots, you'll notice the plot on the right (contour only) has the correct correlation between the contour colors and the color bar but when a surface is added (left plot) the colors no longer match up.

Notes:

1. I've tried `contourslice` but I get the same results. I've posted the code for that below too.
2. How far off the colors are seems to depend on the values of the contour data itself.  If you replace my contour data with `peaks`, it works fine.  However this does not solve the underlying problem.

Code using `contour`:

```
clear all; close all; clc

%define box coordinates
bx = [0 1 1 0 0;0 1 1 0 0]-.5;
by = [0 0 1 1 0;0 0 1 1 0]-.5;
bz = [0 0 0 0 0;1 1 1 1 1]-.5;

%make contour data
[x,y] = meshgrid(-1:.5:1,-1:.5:1);
con = (x.^2+y.^2);

figure(1)
subplot(1,2,1)
box = surf(bx,by,bz); %draw box
set(box,'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'FaceAlpha',1,'EdgeAlpha',0,'EdgeColor',[.5 .5 .5])
hold on
camlight(30,70)

contour(x,y,con) %draw contour
colorbar
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1])
axis equal

subplot(1,2,2)
contour(x,y,con)
axis([-1 1 -1 1])
axis equal
colorbar
set(gcf,'outerposition',[150   150   800   300])
```

Code using `contourslice` instead of `contour` (same problem)

```
clear all; close all; clc

%define box coordinates
bx = [0 1 1 0 0;0 1 1 0 0]-.5;
by = [0 0 1 1 0;0 0 1 1 0]-.5;
bz = [0 0 0 0 0;1 1 1 1 1]-.5;

x = -1:.5:1;
y = x;
z = x;
%make contour data
[xg,yg,zg] = ndgrid(x,y,z);
V = 3-(xg.^2+yg.^2+zg.^2);

figure(1)
subplot(1,2,1)
box = surf(bx,by,bz); %draw box
set(box,'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'FaceAlpha',1,'EdgeAlpha',0,'EdgeColor',[.5 .5 .5])
hold on
camlight(30,70)

contourslice(x,y,z,V,[],[],0) %draw contour
colorbar
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1])
axis equal

subplot(1,2,2)
contour(x,y,V(:,:,3))
axis([-1 1 -1 1])
axis equal
colorbar
set(gcf,'outerposition',[150   150   800   300])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [**`caxis`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) property as you wish:

```
colorbar
caxis([0 2])
...
colorbar
caxis([0 2])
```

[image]

The problem was probably caused, because the surf plot changed the color determining values of your plot. By setting a fixed color axis you can avoid all misinterpretations.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know how I missed that.  I actually used `caxis` as so:

    `caxis([min(min(con)) max(max(con))])`

where `con` is my contour data.  Putting it after `colorbar` seems to preserve having red as the maximum color (rather than yellow).

Thanks again!